# textbox background doesn't follow when textbox expands

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have applied a background for my textbox which works fine when I added .resizeable() jQuery. But when the textbox expands due to the user writing more words/characters the background doesn't expand with the textbox. Ignote the main-note class thats not the problem.

**JS**

```js
$(function() {
     $(".note").resizable();
     $(".main-note" || ".note").draggable();
     $(".main-note-editable" || ".note").on("mousedown", function(e) {
          e.stopPropagation();
          return;
     });
});
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="note" contenteditable="true">
     <span id='close' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)'>
          <img height="30" src="images/close.png" width="30">
     </span>

     <div class="note" contenteditable="true">
          <span id='close' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)'>
               <img height="30" src="images/close.png" width="30">
          </span>
     </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.note {    
    width: 280px;
    height: 130px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    padding: 2;
    word-break: break-word;
    font-family: Note;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-image: url("images/stickynote.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Please don't be lazy. Format your question properly, and show the relevant code (including the `.resizeable()` part you mention)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$(".note").keyup(function(){
    $(this).css('height' , '100%');
});
```

*HTML:*

```
 <div class="note" contenteditable="true"> <span contenteditable='false' id='close' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)'>
            <img src="http://iconizer.net/files/Brightmix/orig/monotone_close_exit_delete.png" height="30" width="30"/></span>
</div>
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8hf3hLgd/4/)

Comment: the problem is the x is in the center how do i make it stay on the left without damaging the code

Comment: You can set a _span_ tag as _contenteditable_ within the _div_ tag [like this...](http://jsfiddle.net/8hf3hLgd/3/) :)

Comment: i tried that but it didnt really work. so i tried something else which was setting the note div as **contenteditable** and then added **align="right" style="vertical-align: top;"** to the img tag. It looked perfect and i though it would work after writing one line but then as the text goes to the next line the image followed. Is there a way to make the image not effected by text?

Comment: Oh, then add ` contenteditable='false'` to the _span_ of the close button. I have updated the code and the JSFiddle :) The issue occurred because the _span_ was assumed _contenteditable_ as well since the parent had the property. So anything you typed was being set as the text within the _span_. Explicitly setting the _span_ contenteditable to false forces the text to be written outside the _span_ but within the _div_